# How To Create Dynamic Arrays Varaibles in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please let me know if it is possible to create dynamically sets of arrays in JS? I tried some thing like this but didn't work

```js
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    var item[i] = [];
}
item1.push(1);
console.log(item1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dynamic array and Dynamic variables are different. `Multidimensional` array will be the solution for your problem.. **You can not create dynamic variables**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to achieve, are you creating dynamic 2D arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.  Assuming you're trying to create a two dimensional array (an array of arrays), you just have to declare the top level array and then reference the first level array with `[x]` array syntax like this:

```
var items = [];
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    items[i] = [];
}

// Here items is an array of arrays where each first level array entry
// is an empty array.  You can then put things into those empty arrays

// You can reference the first level array here
items[1].push(1);
items[1].push(2);
console.log(items[1]);    // [1,2]
```

Comment: Thanks jfriend00, this is exactly what I am looking for